# Aggregate data of the same id and date

Tags: r

I have this dataframe

```
df <- data.frame(id = c(1,1,2), 
                 date = c("2008-08-04 05:45:07","2008-08-04 09:45:07","2008-08-04 05:45:07"), 
                 text = c("stg","another","final"))
```

And I would like to make an aggregation to have this output

```
data.frame(id = c(1,2), 
           date = c("2008-08-04", "2008-08-04"), 
           text = c("stg another","final"))
```

I use this but it gives the input id back

```
aggregate(text ~ date + id, df, paste, sep = " ")
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a suggestion using `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  arrange(date) %>%
  mutate(date_day = format(as.Date(date, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), "%Y-%m-%d")) %>% 
  group_by(id, date_day) %>% 
  summarise(text = paste(text, collapse=" "))
```

Which returns:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 3
# Groups:   id [2]
     id date_day   text       
  <dbl> <chr>      <chr>      
1     1 2008-08-04 stg another
2     2 2008-08-04 final
```

Explanation:

1. Sort by date-time `date` so the string concatenation in the `summarise` step in the end gets the strings in the correct order
2. Extract `date_day` part from date-time
3. Group by `date_day` and `id`
4. For each `date_day` - `id` combination concatenate **all** elements of `text` by using a " " (space) as separator.

## Edit:

Solution using `base` R:

```
aggregate(text ~ format(as.Date(date, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), "%Y-%m-%d") + id, df, paste, sep = " ")
```

Answer (score 0):

In the context of your original question, I would do:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(id = c(1,1,2), 
                 date = c("2008-08-04 05:45:07","2008-08-04 09:45:07","2008-08-04 05:45:07"), 
                 text = c("stg","another","final")) %>%
  mutate(date = str_sub(date, 1, 10))


aggregate(text ~ date + id, df, paste, collapse = " ")
```